# Mysql Load Data Infile slowing down

Tags: mysql, database

I have a large file to load, I have broken this down into files containing 5 millions rows each.

I am running a load date infile command as follows:

```
set foreign_key_checks=0; 
set sql_log_bin=0; 
set unique_checks=0;
load data local infile 'xab' into table logger; 
set unique_checks=1; 
set foreign_key_checks=1; 
set sql_log_bin=1;
```

The first file took 2 minutes

second 3 minutes

third 7 minutes

Now as all files are the same size and very similar data what could be causing the times to increase. I have another 10 files to load and at this rate the last file could take all day...

Comment: In case you have indices following trick can help you:
Run 
`ALTER TABLE tablename DISABLE KEYS`
Then load data and run
`ALTER TABLE tablename ENABLE KEYS`

Comment: Which engine you are using? MYISAM or INNODB?

Comment: I don't think we can disable keys on INNODB.
(Sorry, should of mentioned the engine type earlier)

Comment: @MatthewSmith:- In that case what you are doing is the only option.

Comment: @MatthewSmith, I guess you can drop indices at all, and add them once the data is loaded. Almost the same, but not so beautiful.

Comment: OK, is this going to keep getting slower with more records?
Or is there some post processing happening, and if I leave it for a while before adding more it should help?